# Broken software-center in Trusty Desktop (14.04.3)

Tags: 14.04, software-center, crash, usb-creator

Trouble started when I used `usb-creator-gtk` to create a bootable 14.04.3 USB flash drive. As the app was actually running, `synaptic` (v 0.81.1)  was launched (not by me). Its GUI stayed on screen after `usb-creator-gtk` quietly exited (no error message). I terminated `synaptic` manually in the GUI.

Now `software-center` crashes immediately upon launching it from either cli or gui. `synaptic` on the other hand opens and seems to run correctly. A red and white "one-way street" icon now resides on my Unity bar. Clicking on it, I read above a few menu items:

> An error occurred. Please run Package Manager from the right-click
>   menu or run apt-get from a terminal to see what is wrong. The error
>   message was: Unknown Error: '' (E:Opening
>   /etc/apt/source.list - ifstream::ifstream(13:Permission denied))'.
>   This usually means that your installed packages have unmet
>   dependencies.

What I tried:

**-1-** Below the above blurb are a a few functional menu items, among them "Start Package Manager". That starts `synaptic` in the GUI. Menu "Edit//Reload Package Information" yields:

```
**Could not load all repo items**<BR>
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I never had a CD-ROM for Trusty 14.04.3, so I went on to troubleshoot...

**-2-** Below that, I checked out menu item "Software & Updates".
 
In its usual GUI window, all settings are blanked, all extra ppa's I added in the past 18 months are there. Upon closing a crash report is generated. I checked it in`/var/crash`:

```
$ ls -AFls /var/crash
   total 4512
   0 -rw-rw---- 1 root     whoopsie       0 Dec 29 09:47 .lock
  68 -rw-r----- 1 user      whoopsie   62385 Dec 29 11:06 _usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.1000.crash
   0 -rw-rw---- 1 user      whoopsie       0 Dec 29 11:06 _usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.1000.upload
   0 -rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie       0 Dec 29 11:06 _usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.1000.uploaded
  64 -rw-r----- 1 user      whoopsie   59440 Dec 29 11:32 _usr_bin_update-manager.1000.crash
   0 -rw-rw---- 1 user      whoopsie       0 Dec 29 11:32 _usr_bin_update-manager.1000.upload
   0 -rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie       0 Dec 29 11:32 _usr_bin_update-manager.1000.uploaded
  28 -rw-r----- 1 user      whoopsie   24652 Dec 29 11:08 _usr_share_oneconf_oneconf-service.1000.crash
   0 -rw-rw---- 1 user      whoopsie       0 Dec 29 11:08 _usr_share_oneconf_oneconf-service.1000.upload
   0 -rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie       0 Dec 29 11:08 _usr_share_oneconf_oneconf-service.1000.uploaded
```

Relevant one is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14259246/). The gist of it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 1149, in detect_drivers
     self.apt_cache = apt.Cache()
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
     self.open(progress)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 155, in open
     self._list.read_main_list()
 SystemError: E:Opening /etc/apt/sources.list - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
UserGroups: adm cdrom dip lp lpadmin plugdev sambashare scanner sudo wireshark www-data
_LogindSession: /user/1000.user/c2.session
Architecture: amd64
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
Title: software-properties-gtk crashed with SystemError in open(): E:Opening /etc/apt/sources.list - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
Uname: Linux 3.16.0-50-generic x86_64
UnreportableReason: E:Opening /etc/apt/sources.list - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied), E:The list of sources could not be read., E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

**-3-** Since USC is broken I searched all installed packages with filter `software-center` in `synaptic` and tried to reinstall them followed by reboot using various ways:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center software-center-apt-daemon-plugins appinstall-data oneconf oneconf-common python3-oneconf python-oneconf

$ sudo aptitude reinstall software-center software-center-apt-daemon-plugins appinstall-data oneconf oneconf-common python3-oneconf python-oneconf
```

Both  exited quietly, but nothing changed after reboot, so I tried...

**-4-** Rebuilding the source list:

```
$ sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists* && sudo apt-get update
```

Output to stdout is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14259400/).

Beyond the stated need for a 14.04.3 CD-ROM I do not have and my rebuilding the apt source list, I *seriously* could use some ***help***. Not having any update path is kinda bad.

**EDIT 1:**

```
$ ls -lA /etc/apt/sources.list
-rw-r----- 1 root root 3022 Dec 29 10:38 /etc/apt/sources.list
```

... had never realized before that `/etc/apt/sources.list` was "root root". [Contents](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14262151/) of `/etc/apt/sources.list` show as first uncommented line:
`deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted`
I think this must have been inserted somehow when I launched `usb-creator-gtk` yesterday. I do not recall at all having seen that line before in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output

```
$ ls -lA /etc/apt/sources.list
-rw-r----- 1 root root 3022 Dec 29 10:38 /etc/apt/sources.list
```

we can see that the file's permissions prohibit read access for non-root users and groups. This is wrong and causing the errors you encounter.

To fix these permissions (to be sure, we'll better fix it for all files in `/etc/apt` - no worries, they're readable to other users by default and even must be), please run the following command:

```
sudo chmod -R o+r /etc/apt
```

I'll explain you what its parts are doing:

- `sudo`: Run the following command as root user
- `chmod`: command to change file permissions
- `-R` or `--recursive`: parameter of `chmod`, to operate recursively on the given directory and all contained files and subdirectories
- `o+r`: permission modification rule for `chmod`, tells it to grant (`+`) all others which are not the owner/group (`o`) reading permissions (`r`).
- `/etc/apt`: the file/directory argument for `chmod`